# How to display a single column value instead of the whole row during the drag action in angular

Tags: angular

Hi everyone am working on a basic drag and drop example in angular,the current working is that while dragging a row from one position to another it displays the whole row.My requirement is that it should display only the single column value like "name" instead of the whole row.

Here is my HTML:
dragtable.component.html

```
<table cdkDropList  (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let student of Student" cdkDrag >
            <td>{{student.name}}</td>
            <td>{{student.id}}</td>
            <td>{{student.age}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

ts file:
dragtable.component.ts

```
        import { Component } from '@angular/core';
        import { CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
        @Component({
        selector: 'dragtable-app',
        templateUrl: './dragtable.component.html',
         styleUrls: ['./dragtable.component.css']
          })
          export class DragTableComponent {
             Student = [
             {
                 name: 'abc',
                 id: '1',
                 age: '23'
             },
             {
                name: 'bdc',
                id: '2',
                age: '24'
             },
             {
               name: 'abg',
               id: '3',
              age: '25'
             },
              {
               name: 'dty',
               id: '4',
               age: '26'
              },

             ];

             drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
             moveItemInArray(this.Student, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
              }
             }
```

[image: Initial table]
[image: Drag action]

Comment: you could use ngIf on the inside that if its dragging show only one td with row span else show all td. I haven't tested this but this could work

Comment: @Noob Coder i had to add the cdkDrag item inside the first td i.e  <td cdkDrag>{{student.name}}</td> and it works for me as per the requirement.Thanks for your response which made me to think in a different way to get this solution!

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Comment: @Noob Coder so my solution only works for the first row but while am trying to drag the other two rows i.e ID and age it doesn't work. Can you test this and suggest a workaround?